# NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken _ViewRepeater

Tags: angular

Hi I a getting the following error while creating a table from a custom `ngModule`,

Problems:

1. Not able to understand what the error says.
2. Module is working else where so probably I am the one who is missing something what that could be

```
    ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(ProjectsModule)[InjectionToken _ViewRepeater -> InjectionToken _ViewRepeater -> InjectionToken _ViewRepeater -> InjectionToken _ViewRepeater]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken _ViewRepeater!
    NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(ProjectsModule)[InjectionToken _ViewRepeater -> InjectionToken _ViewRepeater -> InjectionToken _ViewRepeater -> InjectionToken _ViewRepeater]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken _ViewRepeater!
        at NullInjector.get (core.js:11077)
        at R3Injector.get (core.js:11243)
        at R3Injector.get (core.js:11243)
        at R3Injector.get (core.js:11243)
        at NgModuleRef$1.get (core.js:25334)
        at R3Injector.get (core.js:11243)
        at NgModuleRef$1.get (core.js:25334)
        at Object.get (core.js:25048)
        at lookupTokenUsingModuleInjector (core.js:3342)
        at getOrCreateInjectable (core.js:3454)
        at resolvePromise (zone.js:1213)
        at resolvePromise (zone.js:1167)
        at zone.js:1279
        at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:406)
        at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:28654)
        at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:405)
        at Zone.runTask (zone.js:178)
        at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:582)
        at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:491)
        at invokeTask (zone.js:1600)
```

component.html

```
<table cng-table></table
```

component.ts

```
  import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
  import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
  import { ConfigurationGroup } from 'src/app/interfaces/configurationGroup';

  @Component({
    selector: 'app-configuration',
    templateUrl: './configuration.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./configuration.component.css']
  })

export class ConfigurationComponent implements OnInit {

public routeParams!: Object;

public configurationGroups!: ConfigurationGroup[];

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { 
  
  fetch('../assets/names.json')
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(data => {
      this.configurationGroups = JSON.parse(data);
    });
}

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.routeParams = this.route.snapshot.params;
}
```

}

`module.ts` have the `cng-table` module inserted but its a long code and working fine for other components.

Comment: does the module have forRoot/forChild methods which sometimes are needed to pass some extra values to module and inject providers?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 @Component({
selector: 'app-configuration',
templateUrl: './configuration.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./configuration.component.css'],
providers: [
{provide: _VIEW_REPEATER_STRATEGY, useClass: _DisposeViewRepeaterStrategy},
{provide: _COALESCED_STYLE_SCHEDULER, useClass: _CoalescedStyleScheduler}
],
})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).